# Adding a space between CSS classes?

Tags: css

What I mean is this:

```
#page.grid-parent {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px
}
```

This works great - but - I want to be 100% correct.

Should there be a space?

Maybe the ID WITH a CLASS should be together?

Thanks

Comment: if it works great then why you aren't 100% correct?

Comment: Not sure what the question is. If you have an element with an ID of `page` and that same element has a class of `grid-parent` then you are just getting more specific with your styles. If there was a space, you would be targeting a child of `#page` with the class of `grid-parent`.